# How to get application icon from package name and set to textview drawable top in android

Tags: android, android-studio, package, drawable

I have an app in which i have find out application icon from package name and set it to **textview drawable top**. how do i do that please guide me.

code:-

```
  try {
        Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example.testnotification");
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by textView drawable top?

Answer (score 0):

Use `PackagerManager's` [getApplicationIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationIcon%28java.lang.String%29)() for this task:

> Retrieve the icon associated with an application. If it has not
>   defined an icon, the default app icon is returned. Does not return
>   null.

```
try {
     Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.example.testnotification");
     textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, icon , null, null);
  }  catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

**EX**

```
Drawable appIcon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.google.maps");
```

to set on drawable top

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, R.drawable.icon, null, null);
```

check [android:drawableTop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft)

> **setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top,
>   Drawable right, Drawable bottom)** Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear
>   to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text.

Comment: i have textview in which i have to set image as drawableTop

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for set drawable on textview [@satish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6812160/satish)

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon , 0, 0, 0);
```